# Lasgne performs much worse than Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, keras, lasagne

I'm doing a comparison between Keras (with Theano) and Lasagne on a toy regression problem in order to choose one of the two for my final application. As a result of this comparison, I see that Lasagne is performing so much worse than Keras that I'm starting to doubt about my code. Since I'm quite new to both Keras and Lasagne, I would like to check this with someone more experienced than me. The network should be trained to find the mean of a 16x16 matrix. I made different try: first, tried with a 2D conv layer + dense layer (since my final application will require using CNN). Then, since Lasagne results were horrible, I tried with a standard one layer MLP. Again, awful Lasagne performance. I tried to use same specs for both cases: same batch size, same initialization, same optimizer (tested both SGD with Nesterov momentum and ADAM), and of course, same number of epochs and network architecture. Can someone tell me what is going on? Is there something wrong in my code? Why so much difference in the performance? If everything is correct, why Keras perform so much better than Lasagne?

Here the codes I am using:

Keras:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1337)  # for reproducibility

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras import backend as K
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


batch_size = 500
nb_output = 1
nb_epoch = 10

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 16, 16
# number of convolutional filters to use
nb_filters = 20
# size of pooling area for max pooling
pool_size = (2, 2)
# convolution kernel size
kernel_size = (3, 3)


X_train = np.random.randn(10000, 16*16)
Y_train = np.mean(X_train, 1)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = np.random.randn(1000, 16*16)
Y_test = np.mean(X_test, 1)

if K._BACKEND == 'theano':
    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (10000, 1, 16, 16))
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (1000, 1, 16, 16))
else:
    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (10000, 16, 16, 1))    
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (1000, 16, 16, 1))

print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')


model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1],
                        border_mode='same',
                        input_shape=X_train.shape[1:], init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

#model.add(Flatten(input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(nb_output, init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1,  momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)#decay=1e-6,
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=sgd)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
          verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=1)
predicts = model.predict(X_test, batch_size=1000, verbose=0)
print('Test score:', score[0])
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(Y_test, predicts)
```

Lasagne (adapted from [mnist example](https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/examples/mnist.py)):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function

import time

import numpy as np

import theano
import theano.tensor as T

import lasagne

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def load_dataset():
    np.random.seed(1337)
    X_train = np.random.randn(10000, 16*16)
    X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
    Y_train = np.mean(X_train, 1)

    X_test = np.random.randn(1000, 16*16)
    X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
    Y_test = np.mean(X_test, 1)

    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (10000, 1, 16, 16))
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (1000, 1, 16, 16))

    return X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test


def build_cnn(input_var=None):

    network = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None, 1, 16, 16),
                                        input_var=input_var)

    network = lasagne.layers.Conv2DLayer(
            network, num_filters=20, filter_size=(3, 3),
            nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify,
            W=lasagne.init.GlorotUniform())

    network = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(
            network,
            num_units=10,
            nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.sigmoid)

    network = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(
            network,
            num_units=1,
            nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.linear)

    return network


def iterate_minibatches(inputs, targets, batchsize, shuffle=False):
    assert len(inputs) == len(targets)
    if shuffle:
        indices = np.arange(len(inputs))
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
    for start_idx in range(0, len(inputs) - batchsize + 1, batchsize):
        if shuffle:
            excerpt = indices[start_idx:start_idx + batchsize]
        else:
            excerpt = slice(start_idx, start_idx + batchsize)
        yield inputs[excerpt], targets[excerpt]


def main(model='cnn', num_epochs=10):

    print("Loading data...")
    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_dataset()

    input_var = T.tensor4('inputs')
    target_var = T.vector('targets')

    print("Building model and compiling functions...")
    network = build_cnn(input_var)


    prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network)
    loss = lasagne.objectives.squared_error(prediction, target_var)
    loss = loss.mean()

    params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(network, trainable=True)
    updates = lasagne.updates.nesterov_momentum(
            loss, params, learning_rate=0.1, momentum=0.9)
#    updates = lasagne.updates.adam(loss, params)

    test_prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network)
    test_loss = lasagne.objectives.squared_error(test_prediction,
                                                            target_var)
    test_loss = test_loss.mean()


    train_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], loss, updates=updates)

    val_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], test_loss)

    preds = theano.function([input_var], test_prediction)

    print("Starting training...")

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):

        train_err = 0.0
        train_batches = 0
        start_time = time.time()
        for batch in iterate_minibatches(X_train, y_train, 500, shuffle=False):
            inputs, targets = batch
            train_err += train_fn(inputs, targets)
            train_batches += 1

        test_err = 0.0
        test_batches = 0
        for batch in iterate_minibatches(X_test, y_test, 500, shuffle=False):
            inputs, targets = batch
            err = val_fn(inputs, targets)
            test_err += err
            test_batches += 1
        print("Epoch {} of {} took {:.3f}s".format(
            epoch + 1, num_epochs, time.time() - start_time))
        print("  training loss:\t\t{:.6f}".format(train_err / train_batches))
        print("  test loss:\t\t{:.6f}".format(test_err / test_batches))

    pds = preds(X_test)
    plt.scatter(y_test, pds)
    plt.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Both codes are easily adaptable to a one layer MLP. If you run them, you will get this scatter plot at the end:

lasagne:

[image: lasagne]

keras:

[image: keras].

On x axis: true values, on y axis predicted values.